# Bash shell script to modify the images' date created by reading the creation date from XMP file

Tags: bash

Story: I am currently using Apple's Photos app to store my photos. But I found that when I export the photos, their dates created are not the same as their original taken date. Therefore, I want to batch modify the date created by the XMP file generated from the Photos App:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    IFS='
    '
    dir="./Home"
    find $dir -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' x
    do
      fullNoExt=${x%.*}
      filenameNoExt=${fullNoExt##*/}
      fullImgPath=$(find ./Home -not -name "$filenameNoExt.xmp" -name "$filenameNoExt.*")
      fullXMPPath="$fullNoExt.xmp"
      while IFS= read -r line
      do
        title=$(perl -ne 'print and last if s/.*<photoshop:DateCreated>(.*)<\/photoshop:DateCreated>.*/\1/;' <<<  "$line")
        if [[ "$title" == "" ]]
        then
          continue
        else
          ymd=$(echo "$title"| awk '{ print substr($0,1,4)substr($0,6,2)substr($0,9,2)substr($0,12,2)substr($0,15,2) }')
          touch -t $ymd $fullImgPath
        fi
    
      done < "$fullXMPPath"
    done
```

Would anyone comment on or enhance my piece of work :)

Comment: Hm.. 2 crabby down-voters without a comment. At least you have some code! But requests for code review actually belown on [code-review.se] .  This looks reasonable, but I still pre-pend `echo` to the cmd that I want to execute, so I think in your case `echo touch -t $ymd $fullImgPath` and carefully examine the output for unrecoverable errors. THEN when you are certain the output is clean, you can append `| bash`  and the cmds will be executed. Note that any filenames with spaces embedded will need to be correctly quoted or you'll still have problems. ...

Comment: AND I recommend copy/paste your code to https://shellcheck.net and fix any issues flagged there. Good luck.

Comment: sorry, make that [codereview.se] . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter You are so encouraging, thanks so much. Sorry this is my first post in the software community and didnt know theres Code Review section in stackoverflow. And the shellcheck.net is vrey useful! Thank you! That night I found that there are so many bugs in my code and I modified and tested my code before really applied to my 4X GB photos library. And finally I successfully changed the date modified of the photos in 1 hour.

Comment: Awesome! Isn't it great to have a project succeed! Glad this helped. In the future, try to make your Qs here as focused as possible. Where appropriate, include sample input, required output (or actions), your current output, your best attempt to code a solution, AND the exact text of any error messages or warnings you encounter. And it will never hurt to review  [Before asking about problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) section of `tags/bash/info`, and check out the **How to turn a bad script into a good question** section ain the same link. Good luck and keep posting!

Comment: Post your corrected code as an answer, and you can accept it as your answer after 48 hrs. This will give you more reputation points here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Here is the final works that I applied to my 4x GB photo library:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
echo "" > log.txt
find . -type d -mindepth 1| while IFS= read -r dir
do
  echo "start processing $dir"
  find "$dir" -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*.xmp" | while read -r fullXMPPath
  do
    fullNoExt=${fullXMPPath%.*}
    filenameNoExt=${fullNoExt##*/}

    while IFS= read -r line
    do
      title=$(perl -ne 'print and last if s/.*<photoshop:DateCreated>(.*)<\/photoshop:DateCreated>.*/\1/;' <<<  "$line")
      if [[ "$title" == "" ]]
      then
        continue
      else
        ymd=$(echo "$title"| awk '{ print substr($0,1,4)substr($0,6,2)substr($0,9,2)substr($0,12,2)substr($0,15,2) }')
        find "$dir" -type f -not -name "$filenameNoExt.xmp" -name "$filenameNoExt.*" -maxdepth 1 | while read -r fullImgPath
        do
          if test -f "$fullImgPath"
          then
            echo "touch -t $ymd $fullImgPath" >> log.txt
            touch -t $ymd "$fullImgPath"
          else
            let "fileNotExistCnt=$fileNotExistCnt+1"
            echo "$fullImgPath does not exist" >> log.txt
          fi
        done
      fi
    done < "$fullXMPPath"
  done
  echo "==== Done === "
  sleep 30
done

echo "Number of file not exist errors: $fileNotExistCnt"
echo "Number of file not exist errors: $fileNotExistCnt" >> log.txt
```